# How can I easily override SEO Sulu CMS page extension in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, sulu

I want to override the [SeoStructureExtension](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/d5d841b/src/Sulu/Bundle/PageBundle/Content/Structure/SeoStructureExtension.php) with my own implementation, which will support OpenGraph (OG) tags.

What is the easiest way to override it and add additional inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid to say that overriding the `SeoStructureExtension` file can not be achieved very easily... The fields it saves are hardcoded. So the first thing you would have to do is override the `sulu_page.extension.seo` service, which references this class. I would say your best bet to achieve this, is to [decorate this service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html).

The other part you have to extend is the [XML file describing the `page_seo` form](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/c84de32/src/Sulu/Bundle/PageBundle/Resources/config/forms/page_seo.xml). Luckily this part is a little bit easier. Your Sulu installation should already come with a `config/forms` folder, where you can put a [file similar to the original `page_seo` form](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/c84de32/src/Sulu/Bundle/PageBundle/Resources/config/forms/page_seo.xml). Give it the same key (`page_seo`) and only add the new fields you want to add (the name of the properties have to match what you are implementing in the decorated service). If you e.g. want to add a new text field, this file would look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template http://schemas.sulu.io/template/form-1.0.xsd"
>
    <key>page_seo</key>

    <properties>
        <property name="ext/seo/ogTitle" type="text_line">
            <meta>
                <title lang="en">OG Title</title>
            </meta>
        </property>
    </properties>
</form>
```

Mind the `ext/seo/` prefix before `ogTitle`, which is need for the information to be passed to the `SeoStructureExtension`.

I also think that these fields might make sense to be added to the core of Sulu. I would be happy if you [create an issue](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/issues), explaining what fields exactly you need etc. Then we can discuss if we implement it in the core as well, so that you don't have to add this manually in future versions.

Comment: Now there is a problem with when I try to type in the admin with new fields, it don`t allow it: I did like you said, but instead of decorating, I put `parameters:
    sulu_page.extension.seo.class: App\Extensions\SeoStructureExtension` to /config/config.yml. Here are my files: [page_seo.xml](https://gist.github.com/vitalijssilins/3268de97dabd1c56c78f70a074a4200a)
[SeoStructureExtension.php](https://gist.github.com/vitalijssilins/384f460f04862db4b2daa7ba85ba276d)